# Post data request using Volley

Tags: android

i am trying to post data on server using volley but it just give me Volley.ServerError when i click on submit button.But also When i debug my app then all parameters get value but instead of that their is error.

```
public class ConnectWithSpeaker extends AppCompatActivity implements
View.OnClickListener {

LinearLayout linear_layoutcontainer;
Toolbar toolbar;
String url = Constants.SUBMIT_API;
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";
public static final String KEY_COMPANY = "company";
public static final String KEY_SPEAKERID = "speaker_id";
String s_id;
private EditText u_name;
private EditText u_email;
private EditText u_mobile;
private EditText u_company;
private Button submit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect_with_speaker);
    linear_layoutcontainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layoutcontainer);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.customtoolbar);
    TextView title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText("Connect with Speakers");
    toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    u_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    u_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    u_mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
    u_company = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.compny_name);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    s_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("speakerid");
}

private void submitdetails() {
    final String name = u_name.getText().toString().trim();   //trim() remove spaces after&before string
    final String email = u_email.getText().toString().trim();
    final String mobile = u_mobile.getText().toString().trim();
    final String company = u_company.getText().toString().trim();
    final String speaker_id = s_id;
   Toast.makeText(ConnectWithSpeaker.this, "submit details",         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    CustomJSONObjectRequest request2 = new  CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new
     Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println("Response........"+response);
            if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your request is  proceed, we will update you with further updates.",
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(ConnectWithSpeaker.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            params.put(KEY_MOBILE, mobile);
            params.put(KEY_COMPANY, company);
            params.put(KEY_SPEAKERID, speaker_id);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(request2);
}
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == submit) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(u_name.getText().toString())) {
            u_name.setError("Enter Name");
            u_name.requestFocus();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(u_email.getText().toString())) {
            u_email.setError("Enter Email");
            u_email.requestFocus();
        }
        if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(u_mobile.getText().toString())) || (u_mobile.length() < 10 || u_mobile.length() > 15)) {
            u_mobile.setError("Enter valid Mobile No");
            u_mobile.requestFocus();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(u_company.getText().toString())) {
            u_company.setError("Enter Company Name");
            u_company.requestFocus();
        } else {
            submitdetails();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the error in logcat.

```
E/Volley: [1515] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://
```

Comment: have you tried posting the same request on the server using POSTMAN ?  Check if its getting success response from server side. I have not gone through your code, but first make sure at least if its your fault or server issue.

Comment: from this it seems to be server side issue, please try to post here once instead and check http://posttestserver.com/

Comment: I hit the api on postman that give me 
{
  "status": false,
  "message": "<p>The Name field is required.</p>\n<p>The Company Name field is required.</p>\n<p>The Email field is required.</p>\n<p>The Speaker id field is required.</p>\n<p>The Mobile number field is required.</p>\n"
}

and i put all the values.but now i am confused because debugger show me values for each and every string variable.When i execute my app it just skip the printresponse or direct jump on Error statement.

Comment: Put on debug and check the parameters you are posting.

Comment: yes i had checked the response is positive each string variable get a value .

Comment: Check the key names on server side.

Comment: key name are also same their is no difference in them.

Comment: You can send the JsonObject too like convert the `HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap();` and now convert it to jsonobject `new JSONObject(hashmap);` and pass this to volley.

Comment: name="abc"
email="abc@hotmail.com"
mobile="99999999999"
company="abc"
speaker_id="32"
s_is="32

i am getting this response on jsonobject request

Comment: Tried the answer?

Comment: yes not working

Answer (score 0):

I am using this.

```
public class AEJsonRequest extends JsonObjectRequest {

private static int mStatusCode;

public AEJsonRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
    Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

    super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
    ServerHandler.bwLog("sending params", jsonRequest.toString());

}

public AEJsonRequest(String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
}

public static int getStatusCode() {
    return mStatusCode;
}

@Override
protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
    if (volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null) {
        mStatusCode = volleyError.networkResponse.statusCode;
        ServerHandler.bwLog("Error Status code", "" + mStatusCode);
        VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
        volleyError = error;
    }

    return volleyError;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    params.put("Accept", "application/json");
    params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return params;
}

}
```

and call it to

```
  public void submitDetail(HashMap<String, String> hashMap) throws JSONException {
        //param is the JSONobject
        final AEJsonRequest jsonRequest = new AEJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url", new JSONObject(hashMap),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // if status is true, it will return the json data to its calling activity

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }

                });

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                MAX_TIMEOUT_MS,
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonRequest);

    }
```

Hope this'd help